# Ignite 2.4.0 - SqlQuery results do not match with results of query from H2 console

Tags: spring, caching, ignite, gridgain

We implemented a caching solution using ignite 2.0.0 version for data structure that looks like this.

```
public class EntityPO {
  @QuerySqlField(index = true)
  private Integer accessZone;
  @QuerySqlField(index = true)
  private Integer appArea;
  @QuerySqlField(index = true)
  private Integer parentNodeId;
  private Integer dbId;
}

List<EntityPO> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
SqlQuery<String, EntityPO> sql =
    new SqlQuery<>(EntityPO.class, "accessZone = ? and appArea = ? and parentNodeId is not null");
sql.setArgs(accessZoneId, appArea);

  CacheConfiguration<String, EntityPO> cacheconfig = new 
  CacheConfiguration<>(cacheName);
  cacheconfig.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
  cacheconfig.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
  cacheconfig.setIndexedTypes(String.class, EntityPO.class);
  cacheconfig.setOnheapCacheEnabled(true);
  cacheconfig.setBackups(numberOfBackUpCopies);
  cacheconfig.setName(cacheName);
  cacheconfig.setQueryParallelism(1);
  cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheconfig);
```

We have method that looks for node in a particular accessZone and appArea. This method works fine in 2.0.0, we upgraded to the latest version 2.4.0 version and this method no longer returns anything(zero records). We enabled H2 debug console and ran the same query and we are seeing the same atleast 3k records. Downgrading the library back to 2.0.0 makes the code work again. Please let me know if you need more information to help with this question

Results from H2 console.
[H2 Console Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwW0V.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you use persistence, please check a baseline topology for you cluster.
[Baseline Topology](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-activation) is the major feature introduced in the 2.4 version.
Briefly, the baseline topology is a set server nodes that could store the data. Most probably the cause of your issue is to one or several server nodes are not in the baseline.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We are not using persistence, we are using the same config as with 2.0.0 and also when do a dump of all keys in the cache using forEach, i am able see all the entries, it is just that none of them come back when i run my SQLQuery using the Java API. Please let me know if you need additional information to help with my question.

Comment: Another interesting finding was that, when i change my query to `"accessZone = ?"` it works fine, this does not only if i have an "AND" clause.

Comment: @BiswaY How many nodes do you have? What is the affinity key for EntityPO? Are you sure that the data is properly collocated?

Comment: @dmitriy I am running this on local 1 node instance before i deploy it on the cluster. It does not work even on my local 1 node instance.

Comment: @BiswaY Can you provide a small reproducer in GitHub? Please show how you populate the data as well.

Comment: @Dmitriy in my case, removing AffinityKeyMapped annotation fixed by issue, i tried to create a repro case for you, my repro case seem to working just fine. But in my actual app code, it did not work until i removed the annotation as i mentioned above.